# Taking select option text from fancified select option

Tags: jquery, html

```
<select id="from" name="from" required="required" class="fancified">

<option value="1">abc</option>
<option value="2">fgh</option></select>

<div class="trigger">abc</div>

<select id="to" name="to" required="required" class="fancified">

<option value="1">yuo</option>
<option value="2">ioj</option></select>

<div class="trigger">yuo</div>
```

since fancybox is applied to select. I need to get Penang selected option.

which can be done doing this:

```
$('trigger').text();
```

my problem is, I have another drop down using fancified. When i $('trigger').text(); I'm getting text from both. How can I separate it, I need both of them separately.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery is probably returning the first element it finds that matches the selector $('.trigger')

What you will need to do is grab the element being clicked and then maybe use the sibling selector

e.g.

```
$('#from').on('change', function(event){
  $(event.target).siblings('.trigger').text()
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.fancified').change(function() {
    var text = $(this).next().text();
});
```

Also you need to use `.` to target class, so you need `$('.trigger')` instead of `$('trigger')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".fancified option:selected").text();
```

Comment: yes, for example abc and cdf is selected from two. Then I'm getting abccdf like this. How can I seperate it ?

Comment: show both selects in your code, i can see only one..

Answer (score 0):

you could wrap each of the fancy drop downs in a div and then call the child trigger e.g.

```
<div id="trg1"> ... fancy1 ...</div>
<div id="trg2"> ... fancy2 ...</div>
```

You can then select using

```
$('#trg1 trigger').val()
$('#trg2 trigger').val()
```

Comment: I already have id in val so I cannot do that